# Confirmation (return) links missing on hreflang pages WPML Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wpml, hreflang

Im using WPML for my multilangual blog. When i do a Semrush Website Audit i get a lot of errors about "Confirmation (return) links missing on hreflang page"

I have checked the source of the affected pages but i cant figure it what is wrong.

For instance these are the hreflang tags on a page that returns the error.

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://www.foedsie.nl/reizen/indonesie/" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.wewanderwhy.com/indonesia/" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.foedsie.nl/reizen/indonesie/" />`

What is wrong with these hreflang tags? I have no idea how to fix this.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the error may be because each of these pages, the Dutch version at foedsie.nl and the English version at wewanderwhy.com should also include similar hreflang tags pointing back to each other.